# Bash script terminates, taking down its child processes

Tags: linux, bash, process

I'm running a bash script on Linux (3.2.0-29-generic) to spawn about 200 background processes in a loop, and each of these processes would have 10 threads in them. I have observed that once the count goes beyond 175, the script terminates on its own and all the spawned processes are terminated as well. I'm unable to understand why the child processes should go away if the bash script terminated, unless the operating system thought the script was violating a rule and decided to terminate the whole process chain. I'm not capturing return values of any of the commands in the script.

Output of 'ulimit -a' shows that I'm well within limits on the max process count.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15882
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15882
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The system has a dual-core CPU and 2GB RAM, and was not loaded otherwise.

Given below is the script that I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
local_port=1700
remote_port=1700
for i in `seq 0 200`;
do
    sudo tunctl -u uml-net -g uml-net -t tap$i
    sudo brctl addif br0 tap$i
    sudo ifconfig tap$i up
    sudo ./openwrt-uml-vmlinux ubd0=cow$i,openwrt-uml-ext4.img con0=null con=fd:0,fd:1 \
    eth0=tapng,,tap$i
eth1=l2tpv3,,10.x.y.z,$local_port,,$remote_port,0xabab9876abab9876,0xabcd1234abcd1234,2 \
    cgroup_disable=memory mem=24M umid=cow$i init=/etc/preinit > UML_output$i.txt 2>&1 &
    echo "Created UML $i"
    let local_port=local_port+1
    let remote_port=remote_port+1
    sleep 2 
done
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Does system log `/var/log/messages` give any useful info ?

Comment: Pretty interesting. Could you share your script so that we could examine as well? I have an idea about disowning the process but sometimes processes aren't really terminated even if they are not disowned and I don't want to make trial-and-error guess. I want to know what's the real cause of it rather than just fixing it quickly.

Comment: @suspectus: The system does not have the file, but I looked into /var/log/syslog and found nothing useful.

Comment: Could you try with `ulimit -n $(( 1024*32 ))`, how much processes can you run?

Comment: It turns out the that there's some setting pertinent to the executable I'm running that needs to change. Thanks to your replies!